# reading from hive table and updating same table in pyspark - using checkpoint

Tags: hive, pyspark, spark-checkpoint

I am using spark version 2.3 and trying to read hive table in spark as:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.table("emp.emptable")
```

here I am adding a new column with current date from system to the existing dataframe

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
newdf = df.withColumn('LOAD_DATE', F.current_date())
```

and now facing an issue,when I am trying to write this dataframe as hive table

```
newdf.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("emp.emptable")

pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Cannot overwrite table emp.emptable that is also being read from;'
```

so I am checkpointing the dataframe to break the lineage since I am reading and writing from same dataframe

```
checkpointDir = "/hdfs location/temp/tables/"
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(checkpointDir)
df = spark.table("emp.emptable").coalesce(1).checkpoint()
newdf = df.withColumn('LOAD_DATE', F.current_date())
newdf.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("emp.emptable")
```

This way it's working fine and new column has been added to the hive table. but I have to delete the checkpoint files every time it's get created. Is there any best way to break the lineage and write the same dataframe with updated column details and save it to hdfs location or as a hive table.

or is there any way to specify a temp location for checkpoint directory, which will get deleted post the spark session completes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force Spark to evaluate DataFrame operations inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380923/how-to-force-spark-to-evaluate-dataframe-operations-inline)

Comment: I think it's referring to some other problem. I was looking for a solution to break the lineage of dataframe transformation, since I am reading and updating same dataframe and then persisting it as a hive table. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840083/spark-checkpointing-non-streaming-checkpoint-files-can-be-used-in-subsequent-j) post, setting below property is way to go.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints", "true")
```

That question had different context. we wanted to retain the `checkpointed` dataset so did not care to add on cleanup solution.

Setting above property is ***working sometime***(tested scala, java and python) but its *hard to rely* on it. Official document says that by setting this property it `Controls whether to clean checkpoint files if the reference is out of scope.` I don't know what exactly it means because my understanding is that once spark session/context is stopped it should clean it. Would be great if someone can shad light on it.

Regarding

> Is there any best way to break the lineage

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750413/spark-createdataframedf-rdd-df-schema-vs-checkpoint-for-breaking-lineage) question, @BiS found some way to cut the lineage using `createDataFrame(RDD, Schema)` method. I haven't tested it by myself though.

Just FYI, I *don't rely on above property* usually and delete the `checkpointed` directory in code itself to be on safe side.

We can get the `checkpointed` directory like below:

**Scala :**

```
//Set directory
scala> spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("hdfs:///tmp/checkpoint/")

scala> spark.sparkContext.getCheckpointDir.get
res3: String = hdfs://<name-node:port>/tmp/checkpoint/625034b3-c6f1-4ab2-9524-e48dfde589c3

//It gives String so we can use org.apache.hadoop.fs to delete path
```

**PySpark:**

```
// Set directory
>>> spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir('hdfs:///tmp/checkpoint')
>>> t = sc._jsc.sc().getCheckpointDir().get()
>>> t 
u'hdfs://<name-node:port>/tmp/checkpoint/dc99b595-f8fa-4a08-a109-23643e2325ca'

# notice 'u' at the start which means It returns unicode object use str(t)
# Below are the steps to get hadoop file system object and delete

>>> fs = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
fs.exists(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(str(t)))
True

>>> fs.delete(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(str(t)))
True

>>> fs = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
fs.exists(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(str(t)))
False
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yeah, I was reading that post and liked it a lot. That's a nice piece of information related to checkpoint and restart. I want to try  that in Pyspark.

Comment: @vikrantrana: Lineage and check-pointing are always been very tricky and interesting topics to me.

Comment: Yeah.  I saw your couple of great answers on other topics as well. Thanks for your efforts and sharing something really interesting.

Comment: @vikrantrana Sure. Thanks and WC :) It’s always worth sharing.