# Apache Spark retrieve table stored in gcs after deleting cluster on Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I am new to google cloud console, so this might be a trivial question.
I am using free-tier gcp for my data science project. I am running my python notebook on a dataproc cluster.
 I loaded data stored in an external gcs bucket using pyspark as spark dataframe and stored it as a partitioned table using "**df.repartition(100).write.saveAsTable()**" in "**orc**" format in my gcs bucket associated to my project using "**path**" option.
 After this, I deleted my cluster and created a new cluster. 
Now, I'm unable to load the partitioned table using  from my gcs bucket using pyspark. I even set the SparkSession config "**spark.sql.warehouse.dir**" location to the same path where my table was previously saved.
However, I'm able to access the partitioned table in the cluster in which it was created even after closing and restarting SparkSession using "**spark.sql.warehouse.dir**" to the saved table path(using **spark.sql**). But for some reason, I'm unable to do the same after deleting and creating a new cluster.
Please help.
I've spent hours, but couldn't find anything.
Edit:
Screenshots of code

[image]
[image]

Comment: First, could you run `gsutil ls <gcs-folder>` to verify your data is there? Second, could you provide a code sample for both saving and reading so that I can help reproduce.

Comment: Data is there. I can see it using console

Comment: The thing is, I want to query the partitioned table like "spark.sql(" select * from table_name") ", which I can do as long as I haven't turned off the cluster( in which it was created. ) Running the above query in a newly created cluster says "table _name does not exist"! . Amusingly, I can run the above query by closing the current spark session and running it in a new session by setting the warehouse location in a new path as detailed in the question.

Comment: I see, the table metadata is lost after you delete the cluster. You need to recreate the table schema pointing to the data.

Comment: How can I do that? Could you please help?

Comment: I still need you to provide code samples.

Comment: Or you can run SQL directly on the file. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#run-sql-on-files-directly

Comment: I've been trying to upload the screenshots, but for some reason I'm unable to upload.

Comment: But , I saved the file in "orc" format. The page is for "paraquet" format

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the table metadata is stored in Hive metastore, see this [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#saving-to-persistent-tables). After deleting the cluster, the metadata is gone with the metastore, but the data is kept in GCS.

In the new cluster, you can first read the GCS file directly e.g.:

```
df = spark.read.orc('gs://path-to-folder')
```

then create a temp view for further query, see this [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically):

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")

sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM my_table limit 10")
sqlDF.show()
```

Comment: The table is saved as 100 partitions in gcs bucket. How am I going to retrieve all of them as a single table?

Comment: Btw, I want to load the source file as a  dataframe and save it as table in "orc" format by repartitioning it,  so that, when I close my cluster I still have the table without going through the lengthy process of loading all over again. The original file is quite huge.

Comment: Spark won't actually fetch the data when you create the data frame. As long as you don't show all data, it is lazily evaluated across all worker nodes and only fetch the necessary data to the driver (master node).

Comment: You should be able to specify the folder `gs://path-to-folder/`, it will load all files.

Comment: I tried reading both ".jsonl.gz" and ".orc" file in my bucket,I got the same error:                          ""   **ParseException**: "\nmismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 9)\n\n== SQL ==\nselect * from orc.'gs://joel_twitter_data/tables/part-00000-1a1578ff-545f-4329-88f7-30fe8f20d3af-c000.snappy.orc'\n---------^^^\n"  "". Is there any special configuration in SparkSession that needs to be set?

Comment: Where does the snappy come from?

Comment: That's a part of the name of a partition of a table that I earlier saved in"orc" format like shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Btw, how is spark.sql() an improvement over spark.read()? It takes me an hour to load the data using the latter. Would it take the same amount of time with spark.sql()?

Comment: This is the code I've written : df=spark.sql("select * from orc.'gs://joel_twitter_data/tables/part-00000-1a1578ff-545f-4329-88f7-30fe8f20d3af-c000.snappy.orc'")

Comment: I tried saving and reading in the same session, but the query above still doesn't work. I get the same ParseException error. However, I am able to read using spark.sql(" select * from table_name")!

Answer (score 1):

I tried spark.read.orc("gs://path to bucket_ folder") and it worked for me.

Comment: Hey, any idea how to read several JSON files quickly into a dataframe? It takes hours to read!

Comment: Actually, reading files into a dataframe won't trigger the actual read until there is an action like show is called on the dataframe. Why it takes hours for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380923/how-to-force-spark-to-evaluate-dataframe-operations-inline

Comment: I originally had jsonl.gzip files which i decompressed to .json since .gz is not splittable. It seems only one executor is at work here. I'm doing spark.read.json("path"). However, reading "orc" files into dataframe like above takes no time at all ! My CPU utlisation on dataproc is low too ~25%.